# Personal finance web service with account syncing in Germany

Tags: budget, germany, online-tools

I haven't found a single site for personal finance management that does bank syncing in Germany. Some that for example do Barclays, restrict to US or UK accounts.

Is there any law in Germany disallowing this?

Comment: I don't think there is a law against it. comdirect offers multi banking so you can access your other accounts from other banks through the comdirect website. My guess would be: Germans are very conservative when it comes to their money (preferring cash above cards, using "safe" low interest saving accounts instead of stocks) so there just might be no market for such a tool.

Also some (link me) are using desktop apps to manage their personal finances (e.g. MoneyMoney, outbank, numbrs)

Comment: @Sumyrda thanks for the hint, I postet my comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a law against it. For example comdirect offers multi banking so you can access your accounts from other banks through the comdirect website.

My guess would be: Germans are very conservative when it comes to their money (preferring cash above cards, using "safe" low interest saving accounts instead of stocks) so there just might be no market for such a tool.

There are desktop apps with bank syncing that offer different levels of personal finance management. Some I know are [MoneyMoney](http://moneymoney-app.com), [outbank](https://outbankapp.com), [numbrs](https://www.centralway.com/de/), [GNUCash](https://www.gnucash.org) and [StarMoney](https://www.starmoney.de/).

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know StarMoney has also a [web service](https://www.starmoney.de/index.php?id=starmoneyweb) for banking.